# MSSQL trigger inserting few rows depends on list in another table column

Tags: sql, loops, triggers

I have created two tables which are in relation [Configuration] and [ConfigurationDetails], I used foreign key on 'id' column in [Configuration] and 'config_id' in [ConfigurationDetails].

Now I want to create trigger on [Configuration] which will be fire when I do INSERT on [Configuration]. To this place I have no problem, but problem is in the body of trigger, becouse my trigger should insert few rows into [ConfigurationDetails] table. Below is an example that I created manually what I want to achieve:

This is the example [Configuration] row:

```
c.174 + c.179 + c.183 + e.SR04 +
```

after it is inserted, the trigger is relased. And here is my problem, I don't know how to split that string that proper 'id' were inserted into correct column in [ConfigurationDetails] table. If the first index of id is 'c.', put this in 'channel_id' column and analogous situation in case the first index is 'e'. Like in example below :

```
id  config_id   utility_id  channel_id  equipment_id    sign
3   181 2   174 NULL    +         
4   181 2   179 NULL    +         
5   181 2   183 NULL    +         
6   181 2   NULL    15  +
```

[Example insert after trigger done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZv3P.png)

I dont know how to resolve this issue, maybe wrote loop over indexes in configuration row? Maybe someon can give me tip how to bit this problem?

Thanks,
mrfy

Comment: Eh... I'm going to say this is not the correct design of those tables. If you are inserting values based on a concatenation of column lists it looks like you need a many to many relationship.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know that this is not maybe the best solution but this is the easiest way to keep lots of information in only one row. I don't need to create many tables, is there possibility to resolve this issue keep going my way of thinking?

Comment: I did not suggest making many tables. Just multiple rows.

Comment: You open my eyes, I can change my approach to this matter. What do you thinking about swap priority of this tables, and create trigger on [ConfigurationDetails] table which create expression row based on many rows ?